# How force list (initially with English only) of localizations in iOS 7 app?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, localization

I have:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {
        // Force use of English.
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

This forced libraries like HockeySDK to use English only.  But `localizedDescription` of for example `NSError`s from iOS are still in the user selected language.  When I have a payment error in `SKPaymentTransaction` I get a Dutch (my current iPhone language) description in a further English (my own code) alert; looks really sloppy.

How can I force **all** texts in my whole app to be always in English?

Or in general: How can I make sure that iOS always choses a language from a list (which currently only contains "en") that I define?

Comment: Hi, Would that be ONLY for the errors, or do you want to turn off localization for your entire app?

Comment: @FlorianBurel Good point, I changed title and description.